# Using multiple "or" with "and" statements

Tags: python, long-lines

```
def check_over(mark):

    ######################################
    #This checks for a win################
    ######################################
    if board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark
    or board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark
    or board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark
    or board[1] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[7] == mark
    or board[2] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[8] == mark
    or board[3] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[9] == mark
    or board[1] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[9] == mark
    or board[3] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[7] == mark:
        print(f'{mark} won!')
```

This code yields the following error when I try to call it:

```
    if board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark
       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This function is meant to check for a win in a tic-tac-toe game based on a python list named board.

Where is the problem?

Comment: or you could use parenthesis around your if condition. like `if (...multi-lines condition):`

Comment: See [Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) if you're interested about specifics.

Comment: You can use `any` and `all` to avoid very long `or` and `and` chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SyntaxError` is occuring because you're not using `\` characters to break across multiple lines

```py
def check_over(mark):
    ######################################
    #This checks for a win################
    ######################################
    if board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark \
    or board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark \
    or board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark \
    or board[1] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[7] == mark \ 
    or board[2] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[8] == mark \
    or board[3] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[9] == mark \
    or board[1] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[9] == mark \
    or board[3] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[7] == mark:
        print(f'{mark} won!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have have new lines in the middle of your line in python.
Try the following:

```
if board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and board[3] == mark  or board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark or board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark and board[9] == mark or board[1] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[7] == mark or board[2] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[8] == mark or board[3] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[9] == mark or board[1] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[9] == mark or board[3] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[7] == mark:
    print(f'{mark} won!')
```